# Design is hard on the eyes due to black/white contrast with info boxes

Tags: discussion, design

This is what the front page of ServerFault looks like to new users: [image: Front page of ServerFault for new users]

I understand that the top bar is black across all sites, and that the cookie notice and mini-tour are supposed to be visible, but in combination with the white background, this looks more like a zebra than a useful website.

Could we reduce the contrast a bit, to make the design easier on the eyes?

Comment: Those are shown to first time visitors. Try dismissing them.

Comment: @Michael I know, but this is about the initial impression - in the few seconds users spend looking at a new site, they aren't going to close them. And if they leave, it's too late.

Comment: I see your point, but also suspect that many, if not most, _new_ users come here in a full panic about a problem more pressing than those extra bars, and probably aren't going to run away.

Comment: I hate the fact that those ridiculous cookie disclaimers are appearing on virtually every site now. But, unfortunately, it's not legal to bash in the heads of idiot lawmakers until they start acting sensibly. We're stuck with them for now...

Comment: Code Review (where you are a member) looks no different to me (where I'm not registered). Since it's a site-wide issue and (presumably) you want the same fix everywhere it's best to bring this up on the main [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). The people whom *might* fix it may not see your post here for some time.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Many other sites do this in a much less intrusive way, it's Stack Exchange's own decision to make the banners look like that and force users to (in theory) read dozens of legal pages before being able to close them.